# Simplest expression for a continuous PDF with up to $n$ moments

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As the title says, I wonder whether there is some canonical form for a continuous probability distribution function (pdf) for which only the first $n$ moments may be non-vanishing. If not, I am interested in the cases $n=2,3,4$. Or at least, maybe I can approximate perturbatively the pdf using information about the moments?

Comment: The question is too short, please provide us some context

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear. What additional information do you need?

Comment: It is certainly clear for you and English speeking people specialised in probability, for others adding an example is always helpful for instance. Also, I don't know what a PDF is in English, if you write the full name I surely would recognize it from my mother tongue. Note I didn't dowvot your question, 4-lines questions are rarely well received so I encourage improvment for those.

Comment: You can find the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Definition) $M(t)=\left< e^{tX}\right>=1+t\left<X\right>+\frac{t^2}{2}\left<X^2\right>+\cdots $ which in your case will be an $n$th order polynomial. Then the PDF is the Fourier transform of $M(it)$ (up to some considerations of domains, etc)

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg Thank you for the clarification! I used an abbreviation in the title to  save space, but I edited the main text to make it more clear.

Comment: @Sal The Fourier transform would be $\sum _n \frac{1}{n!} \intop dt e^{itx}i^nt^n<x^n>$

Comment: There's no such thing. Every even moment of a probability distribution is non-vanishing (but possibly infinite), unless the distribution is a unit mass at $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, I can't believe I missed it.

Comment: @proton ok for me now. +1

Comment: @proton The Fourier transform is $\tilde{M}(x)\propto \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dt \ e^{\pm itx} M(it)$